# After add firebase crash analytics script get Shell Script Invocation Warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

hello I add firebase crash analytics script and get shell script warning
from Facebook sdk.

how can I remove this ?

> warning: dump_syms:
>   /Users/MyName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyPro-bgqelwggbpabjofxdrnjvhogdatv/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/MyPro.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Loco,
>   architecture : in compilation unit
>   '/Users/demmel/ios-sdk/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/FBSDKTriStateBOOL.m'
>   (offset 0x1028b9):
>
> warning: dump_syms:
>   /Users/MyName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyPro-bgqelwggbpabjofxdrnjvhogdatv/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/MyPro.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Loco,
>   architecture : the DIE at offset 0x10291b has a DW_AT_abstract_origin
>   attribute referring to the die at offset 0x102936, which either was
>   not marked as an inline, or comes later in the file
>
> warning: dump_syms:
>   /Users/MyName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyPro-bgqelwggbpabjofxdrnjvhogdatv/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/MyPro.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Loco,
>   architecture : warning: function at offset 0x10291b has no name

Comment: is the script phase the last build step? if not - move it down

Comment: I don't understand what you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

try this steps:

> 1) open build phases -> run script
>
> 2)Click  on the run script only when installing

Comment: But firebase crash report need run this script every time app build.

Comment: this is from firebase sdk  - "Upload symbol files
In order to view human-readable crash reports, you need to upload symbol files after each build. This can be done automatically by adding a run script to Xcode:"

Comment: @Frank  you can help me with this ?